# Measure battery drain for a specific App or package name using ADB Commands

Tags: android, performance, adb, batterymanager

Measure battery drain using ADB commands for a specific package name.

Battery stats for the package name since the last charge to the android device. To measure performance of the device or to automate the non-functional testing for your application in the android devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can measure the battery drain using the following command

```
adb shell dumpsys batterystats --charged <packageName>
```

For more information on the batterystats refer this link: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/power/batterystats

Comment: According to [Batterystats Walkthrough](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/battery-historian-charts.html), the estimated power use (mAh) by UID and peripheral is currently an "_extremely rough estimate and should not be considered experiment data_". So beware if you need precise measurement.

Comment: Is it possible to increase the sensitivity of the android Batterystats? Currently, it provides information 2 digits after the decimal point. I want to increase 3 or 4 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: @foo It seems this information was removed from the page, is it usable for experimentation now?

Comment: @Stefan sorry I'm not sure as I'm not really keeping up on this.